# Two Different Shipping Methods

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping-methods, delivery

Hi I am looking to add 2 different shipping methods

Normal Delivery

```
UK - £10+ - Free
UK - Less than £10 - £2.95
```

Recorded Delivery

```
UK - 1KG+ - £5
UK - Less than 1KG - £3.95
```

I can see Magento has table rates built in eg weight vs destination & price vs destination

However from what I can see I can only have 1 and not both. How would it be possible to have both for different delivery methods?

Comment: with the use of this extension you can achieve your functionality http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-table-rates-by-amasty.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend installing the following module

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html

Examples can be found here of different combinations

http://wiki.webshopapps.com/extensions/matrix-rates

Comment: Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate.

Comment: Anyone knows how to give free shipping using Webshopapps  Matrix Rates in SHopping Cart Pricing rule?

Comment: @Rathinam if it's on a shopping cart price rule I believe you just enable the free shipping method and set the threshold on it to something really high 9999, then in your rule say allow free shipping and it should work. this obviously doesn't take into consideration any rules you have with matrix rates though.

Comment: @WillWright Yes you are right, it is working if we set threshold  9999, my condition i need to give free shipping only for select zipcode only, if ypou have any idea about that?

Comment: @Rathinam is it a one off thing or do you always want to give a zip code free delivery? you can do multiple lines per zip code so you could have zip code 12345 on two lines one with a cost of $5.00 one with a cost of $0.00. If you want to do a shopping cart price rule though you wouldn't be able to do that by zip code.

Comment: OKay, is any other possibilities can i apply free shipping using zipcode?